# CodeIgniter Tutorial Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm working on the second half of the CodeIgniter beginners tutorial which can be found at http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html and like many others I can't get it to work properly.

The post index works fine but every time I click on "view article" I just get a 404 message.

I've looked over a number of posts about this and tried a number of solutions that were offered but so far nothing has worked which is driving me slightly crazy considering I copied and pasted  the code from the tutorial to make sure I didn't copy it wrong by mistake.

My code is as follows:

Controller:

```
class News extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('news_model');
            $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index()
    {
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
    $data['title'] = 'News archive';
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');}
    public function view($slug = NULL)
    {
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
    if (empty($data['news']))
    {
            show_404();
    }
    $data['title'] = $data['news']['title'];
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    }
```

Model:

```
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->load->database();
    }
    public function get_news($slug = FALSE){
    if ($slug === FALSE)
    {
            $query = $this->db->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();}}
```

View:

view.php

```
echo '<h2>'.$news['title'].'</h2>';
echo $news['text'];
```

index.php

```
    <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
    <?php foreach ($news as $news): ?>
    <h3><?php echo $news['title'] ?></h3>
    <div class="main">
    <?php echo $news['text'] ?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="news/<?php echo $news['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

routes.php

```
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello Tessa. This would be great question for [CodeIgniter forum](http://forum.codeigniter.com).

Comment: At the start of of the `view()` controller method (i.e. just after the `public function` line), put in `echo 1; exit()` to see if it gets that far.

Comment: (By the way, you'll find this rather easier to work with if you improve your indentation. Some lines have braces on the end, whereas these should really be on their own line, with each brace section being a different level of nested indent).

Comment: Oh, and my code doesn't really look like that but for some reason when I posted it to the forum it wasn't being recognized as one piece of code so I had to condense some of it.

Answer (score -1):

Did you managed to work it out?

What is the `href` in the anchor provides you with? I believe you should use the `site_url()` method to fix it, so the anchor should be:

```
<p><a href="<?= site_url(); ?>news/<?= $news['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>
```

I swapped the

Comment: Thanks for posting... I decided to stop being lazy and read the manual ;-)

Comment: It always comes to this at the end. :)